# Gremlin query for a property with automatic creation of vertices containing this property if not existent

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I want to create a query that looks for vertices which hold a property value out of a list of values and create a new Vertex with the property.

Example:

Input: List of names like "Frank", "Sam", "Peter"
Query: Searches for person nodes with the name property set to one of the above names, if non existent, create the person node and add the property with the missing name.

Node with name property "Sam" exists before query
After the query three nodes exist one with the name property "Frank", one with the name "Sam" (unchanged) and one with the name property "Peter".

Help is appreciated by the gremlin noob ;-)

I might use inject() for the list and coalesce for creating a node, but I have no idea how to add the name I am iterating to the property in the newly created vertex.

Comment: Which Gremlin version are you using? If it is at least 3.6.0 the answer to you question becomes simpler as the new `mergeV` step can be used. Knowing that will help write an appropriate answer,

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am using neptune and they released a new version just a couple of days ago. This version is using gremlin > 3.6.0 and it should understand the MergeV command.
I am using the gremlin.net nuget package but I did not find an example of using this command exacly. Maybe somebody can help...

Comment: OK I'll add an answer showing `mergeV`

Answer (score 2):

Using TinkerGraph and the Gremlin Console, we can create a simple graph containing a node for 'Sam'

```java
gremlin> g=TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]

gremlin> g.addV('Person').property('name','Sam')
==>v[32]
```

We can then write a query that takes advantage of the new `mergeV` step to add the missing people.

```java
gremlin> g.inject([(T.label):'Person','name':'Sam'],
......1>          [(T.label):'Person','name':'Peter'],
......2>          [(T.label):'Person','name':'Frank']).
......3>          mergeV() 
==>v[32]
==>v[34]
==>v[36]
```

We can check to see that everyone now exists in the graph:

```java
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[id:32,label:Person,name:[Sam]]
==>[id:34,label:Person,name:[Peter]]
==>[id:36,label:Person,name:[Frank]]
```

Before TinkerPop 3.6.x was released, doing this would require a more complex query that uses `inject` and `coalesce`. There are many ways that `mergeV` can be used and there are several examples in the [TinkerPop documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#mergevertex-step).

To use the query above with Amazon Neptune, the Neptune Engine version needs to be at least 1.2.1.0. That Engine contains support for TinkerPop 3.6.x.

Comment: I upgraded our neptune instance, and I can now use the merge feature.

Unfortunately my knowledge of gremlin is not as good to solve my task...

Comment: Happy to try to help but that sounds like a different question than the original one in this post. Perhaps you could open a new question that describes the product/box scenario.

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately I just changed the question...

Comment: Please open a new question rather than do that. People invest time in answering questions as asked. This is now a totally different question. Someone finding the answer to the original question will now be totally confused. I recommend undoing your edit and opening a new question.